# Could someone elucidate why softtabstop is not working and other gaps in understanding?

Tags: vim

I've read the following articles:

1. http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/
2. https://medium.com/@arisweedler/tab-settings-in-vim-1ea0863c5990

To try and understand what things like `tabstop`, `shiftwidth` and `softtabstop` mean.
Here's what I get so far:

1. `tabstop` sets the way that tab appears on the vim editor. If you have `set ts=4`, then it will look like you have 4 spaces whenever you press on the tab key on your keyboard. If you have  `set ts=50`, then it will look like each time you press Tab, you get 50 spaces. In the case that you have `set expandtab`, the characters will be 50 spaces, otherwise you will just have 1 tab character that seems like 50 spaces (so just 1 byte from ASCII?, seems a bit weird).
2. `shiftwidth` sets the amount of indentation for things like `<<`, `>>`, `==`, and also autoindent. So this means that you know, if you have `set sw=5`, and say `ts=4`, then when `>>` is typed, it puts in 1 tab and 1 space and does some math as such.
3. `softtabstop` I'm not so sure about. From what I have read, the sources seem to have different explanations.

Source 1 says:

> If you prefer to work with tab characters then it is a good idea to
>   ensure that tabstop == softtabstop. This makes it less likely that
>   you’ll end up with a mixture of tabs and spaces for indentation.
>
> If you prefer to work with spaces, then it is preferable to ensure
>   that softtabstop == shiftwidth. This way, you can expect the same
>   number of spaces to be inserted whether you press the tab key in
>   insert mode, or use the indentation commands in normal/visual modes.

Source 2 says:

> softtabstop: Referred to for the tab key and backspace key. How much
>   whitespace should be inserted when the tab key is pressed? And how
>   much whitespace should be removed when the backspace key is pressed?

First of all, I don't really know how to reconcile Source 1 and Source 2. Why does `shiftwidth` matter (source 1), if we only do it for the tab key and backspace key (source 2). The `shiftwidth` character should control how much space is added during `>>`, etc, right? Why does it matter for spaces?

"If you prefer to work with tab characters then it is a good idea to ensure that tabstop == softtabstop.": this sort of makes sense. `softtabstop` determines how much space each keypress of Tab makes, and if there is discord between `tabstop` and `softtabstop` then we could end up using spaces to make things even out.

Lastly, I was trying out some of the examples in Source 2 at the bottom. (Note in my vimrc I have the following lines and only this line affecting whitespace: `set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab`)

I made the following changes in a new file:

```
:set ts=5 sts=3
:retab
```

When I pressed the Tab key, contradictory to what the author of article 2 said, I was getting 4 spaces, not 3. So did he say something wrong? I then set `shiftwidth` to 3, and NOW I was getting 3 spaces when I pressed the tab key (and also when I did `>>`). I don't know the meaning of this. Was he wrong?

Based on these observations, can anyone tell me what `sts` is actually doing? When we have a tab character no matter what the `ts` is it always 1 byte? Does `sw` affect Tab key presses? Is there any other misunderstanding I have about these parameters? Vim is hard.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have set ts=50, then it will look like each time you press Tab, you get 50 spaces.

Nope. While inserting new tabs by Vim it's the `softtabstop` option which comes to play. But `sts` value is recalculated into `ts` one. So if you have `ts=50` and `sts=100` (and also `noexpandtab`, of course) then you get 2 hard tabs (`\x9` byte) in the buffer.

To disable this feature you can `set sts=0`. In this case a tab will be just a tab / `tabstop`.

Comment: Is everything else I have written above correct? Also I'm not sure if what you're saying is true. I tried `set noet sw=0 ts=50 sts=100`, and pressing tab once. It just seems to give me one tab (character count in file is 2, which includes the newline of course)

Comment: @herophant Are you sure? Can you reproduce this behaviour with `vim --clean`?